# XSLT Merging two nodes into one

Tags: xslt

I'm looking to merge two nodes (or more) into one. I've worked with xslt for a little while, but mainly doing pretty simple stuff. I've done much searching, but solutions have been over my head so I haven't been able to adapt to my own problem. Closest thing I've found is an answer by Martin Honnen using a function he built called "eliminate-deep-equal-duplicates".

My problem is I can have two or more `<Coverage>` nodes that have "CoverageCd=ADDRL" and I need to combine these nodes only, no other Coverage nodes with other CoverageCd values. So I want to merge the ADDRL nodes but keep the unique "Addr" child node for all ADDRL iterations.

One other caveat is that I need to have the count of merged ADDRL nodes and place in the "OptionValue" element. So In my example where I have two ADDRL Coverage nodes my OptionValue needs to be 2. My xslt currently almost gives me what I need, but duplicates the MiscParty/GeneralPartyInfo which I don't want. And while I have the variable AddrlCount that gives me the correct value to place in my OptionValue,

I'm not quite sure how to incorporate that into the current xslt. I know my main problem is that I'm not exactly sure what the "eliminate-deep-equal-duplicates" function is doing. Any help anyone could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Input XML

```
<ACORD>
    <InsuranceSvcRq>
        <HomePolicyQuoteInqRq>
            <HomeLineBusiness>
                <Dwell LocationRef="000b3c6b-264f-83b7-1b80-006a3ce1f40e">
      <PolicyTypeCd>06</PolicyTypeCd>
      <PurchaseDt>2011-05-10</PurchaseDt>
      <Construction>
        <ConstructionCd>F</ConstructionCd>
        <com.ormutual_recontype>Standard</com.ormutual_recontype>
        <YearBuilt>1988</YearBuilt>
        <BldgArea>
          <NumUnits>1200</NumUnits>
          <UnitMeasurementCd>Square Foot</UnitMeasurementCd>
        </BldgArea>
      </Construction>
                    <Coverage>
                        <CoverageCd>MEDPM</CoverageCd>
                        <Limit>
                            <FormatInteger>1000</FormatInteger>
                        </Limit>
                    </Coverage>
                    <Coverage>
                        <CoverageCd>LAC</CoverageCd>
                        <Limit>
                            <FormatInteger>50000</FormatInteger>
                        </Limit>
                    </Coverage>
                    <Coverage>
                        <CoverageCd>ADDRL</CoverageCd>
                        <Option>
                            <OptionTypeCd>Num1</OptionTypeCd>
                            <OptionValue>1</OptionValue>
                        </Option>
                        <MiscParty>
                            <GeneralPartyInfo>
                                <Addr>
                                    <AddrTypeCd>StreetAddress</AddrTypeCd>
                                    <Addr1>9325 SW CAMILLE TER</Addr1>
                                    <City>PORTLAND</City>
                                    <StateProvCd>OR</StateProvCd>
                                    <PostalCode>97223</PostalCode>
                                    <County>WASHINGTON</County>
                                </Addr>
                            </GeneralPartyInfo>
                        </MiscParty>
                    </Coverage>
                    <Coverage>
                        <CoverageCd>ADDRL</CoverageCd>
                        <Option>
                            <OptionTypeCd>Num1</OptionTypeCd>
                            <OptionValue>1</OptionValue>
                        </Option>
                        <MiscParty>
                            <GeneralPartyInfo>
                                <Addr>
                                    <AddrTypeCd>StreetAddress</AddrTypeCd>
                                    <Addr1>2222 ANDREW AVE NW</Addr1>
                                    <City>SALEM</City>
                                    <StateProvCd>OR</StateProvCd>
                                    <PostalCode>97304</PostalCode>
                                    <County>POLK</County>
                                </Addr>
                            </GeneralPartyInfo>
                        </MiscParty>
                    </Coverage>
                </Dwell>
            </HomeLineBusiness>
        </HomePolicyQuoteInqRq>
    </InsuranceSvcRq>
</ACORD>
```

Desired Output

```
<ACORD>
    <InsuranceSvcRq>
        <HomePolicyQuoteInqRq>
            <HomeLineBusiness>
                <Dwell LocationRef="000b3c6b-264f-83b7-1b80-006a3ce1f40e">
      <PolicyTypeCd>06</PolicyTypeCd>
      <PurchaseDt>2011-05-10</PurchaseDt>
      <Construction>
        <ConstructionCd>F</ConstructionCd>
        <com.ormutual_recontype>Standard</com.ormutual_recontype>
        <YearBuilt>1988</YearBuilt>
        <BldgArea>
          <NumUnits>1200</NumUnits>
          <UnitMeasurementCd>Square Foot</UnitMeasurementCd>
        </BldgArea>
      </Construction>
                    <Coverage>
                        <CoverageCd>MEDPM</CoverageCd>
                        <Limit>
                            <FormatInteger>1000</FormatInteger>
                        </Limit>
                    </Coverage>
                    <Coverage>
                        <CoverageCd>LAC</CoverageCd>
                        <Limit>
                            <FormatInteger>50000</FormatInteger>
                        </Limit>
                    </Coverage>
                    <Coverage>
                        <CoverageCd>ADDRL</CoverageCd>
                        <Option>
                            <OptionTypeCd>Num1</OptionTypeCd>
                            <OptionValue>2</OptionValue>
                        </Option>
                        <MiscParty>
                            <GeneralPartyInfo>
                                <Addr>
                                    <AddrTypeCd>StreetAddress</AddrTypeCd>
                                    <Addr1>9325 SW CAMILLE TER</Addr1>
                                    <City>PORTLAND</City>
                                    <StateProvCd>OR</StateProvCd>
                                    <PostalCode>97223</PostalCode>
                                    <County>WASHINGTON</County>
                                </Addr>
                                <Addr>
                                    <AddrTypeCd>StreetAddress</AddrTypeCd>
                                    <Addr1>2222 ANDREW AVE NW</Addr1>
                                    <City>SALEM</City>
                                    <StateProvCd>OR</StateProvCd>
                                    <PostalCode>97304</PostalCode>
                                    <County>POLK</County>
                                </Addr>
                            </GeneralPartyInfo>
                        </MiscParty>
                    </Coverage>
                </Dwell>
            </HomeLineBusiness>
        </HomePolicyQuoteInqRq>
    </InsuranceSvcRq>
</ACORD>
```

My attempt at the xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com" xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf" exclude-result-prefixes="xs functx mf">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:function name="functx:index-of-node" as="xs:integer*">
        <xsl:param name="nodes" as="node()*"/>
        <xsl:param name="nodeToFind" as="node()"/>

        <xsl:sequence select="   for $seq in (1 to count($nodes))   return $seq[$nodes[$seq] is $nodeToFind]  "/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:function name="mf:eliminate-deep-equal-duplicates" as="node()*">
        <xsl:param name="nodes"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="for $node in $nodes             return $node[not(some $preceding-node in $nodes[position() lt functx:index-of-node($nodes, $node)] satisfies deep-equal($node, $preceding-node))]"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:variable name="AddrlCount" select="count(ACORD/InsuranceSvcRq/HomePolicyQuoteInqRq/HomeLineBusiness/Dwell/Coverage[./CoverageCd='ADDRL'])"/>
    <xsl:template match="ACORD/InsuranceSvcRq/HomePolicyQuoteInqRq/HomeLineBusiness/Dwell">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="Coverage" group-by="CoverageCd">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="Coverage[./CoverageCd='ADDRL'],
                     mf:eliminate-deep-equal-duplicates(current-group()/(* except (Addr))),
                     Addr"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are grouping `Coverage` elements by `CoverageCd` values

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="Coverage" group-by="CoverageCd">
```

So, at this point you are positioned on a `Coverage` element (ones with the first occurrence of a `CoverageCd` value). But you then do this...

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Coverage[./CoverageCd='ADDRL'],
```

This means you are looking for a `Coverage` element that is a child of a covering `Coverage` element, which would return element. Similarly, where you do this....

```
mf:eliminate-deep-equal-duplicates(current-group()/(* except (Addr)))
```

`current-group()` returns all `Coverage` elements with the same code, none of which have `Addr` elements, so this selects all elements.

What you can possibly do, is just replace the statement with this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="mf:eliminate-deep-equal-duplicates(current-group()/*)" />
```

Then you can have templates for matching elements you wish to change.

Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com" xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf" exclude-result-prefixes="xs functx mf">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:function name="functx:index-of-node" as="xs:integer*">
        <xsl:param name="nodes" as="node()*"/>
        <xsl:param name="nodeToFind" as="node()"/>

        <xsl:sequence select="   for $seq in (1 to count($nodes))   return $seq[$nodes[$seq] is $nodeToFind]  "/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:function name="mf:eliminate-deep-equal-duplicates" as="node()*">
        <xsl:param name="nodes"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="for $node in $nodes             return $node[not(some $preceding-node in $nodes[position() lt functx:index-of-node($nodes, $node)] satisfies deep-equal($node, $preceding-node))]"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ACORD/InsuranceSvcRq/HomePolicyQuoteInqRq/HomeLineBusiness/Dwell">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node() except Coverage" />
            <xsl:for-each-group select="Coverage" group-by="CoverageCd">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="mf:eliminate-deep-equal-duplicates(current-group()/*)" />
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="OptionValue">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="count(mf:eliminate-deep-equal-duplicates(current-group()/MiscParty/GeneralPartyInfo/Addr))" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="GeneralPartyInfo">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="mf:eliminate-deep-equal-duplicates(current-group()/MiscParty/GeneralPartyInfo/Addr)" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To be honest, I don't think you even need the `mf:eliminate-deep-equal-duplicates` in this particular case. This XSLT also produces the result you need

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com" xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf" exclude-result-prefixes="xs functx mf">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ACORD/InsuranceSvcRq/HomePolicyQuoteInqRq/HomeLineBusiness/Dwell">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node() except Coverage" />
            <xsl:for-each-group select="Coverage" group-by="CoverageCd">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates  />
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="OptionValue">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="count(current-group()/MiscParty/GeneralPartyInfo/Addr)" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="GeneralPartyInfo">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/MiscParty/GeneralPartyInfo/Addr" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tim. Option #2 is much simpler and seems to be working (almost) just right. But, I left out something that I thought wouldn't matter... I do have other elements under /Dwell node (including the LocationRef attribute) that I need to pick up too but hadn't shown them in the xml. And right now all those elements are going away because I'm only selecting the Coverage nodes. Not surprising... but I've played around with this for a while this morning with no success. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: If you want to edit your question to amend the XML to show just one other element under `Dwell` as an example, then I don't think it should be too hard to fix the XSLT.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I've added some other elements under Dwell in my examples above.

Comment: I've amended the XSLT to copy across all other elements under `Dwell`. It's the line that does `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node() except Coverage" />`

Comment: Thanks Tim. I was trying to do the same kind of thing with a "not", which wasn't working. This works perfectly. Thanks again for your help!